# report footer a & b different image on different page

Tags: crystal-reports

crystal version 11.5.12.1838

I'm trying to get images to print in the report footer section, with one image on 'report footer a' on one page and a new page with a different image in 'report footer b'.

I cannot get this to work and only the page and image contained in report footer a will print.  There are no suppression formulae in the report footer section (actually no formulae of any description in this section).  Is it possible to do this?

[edit 1]
This is a subreport and it looks like there is some hard limit on the number of pages in the overall report. If I add a report footer b, c, d and put images in them and set "new page after", none of them are printed.  Also tried adding background colours to each of the report footer subsections - still only get 'report footer a' followed by a blank page.

[edit 2]
The whole subreport is set to be suppressed if a variable=0.  The strange behaviour I'm seeing now is that if the subreport is not suppressed (with the suppresion formula still present), then only 'report footer a' in the subreport is shown.  If I remove the subreport suppression completely, then all of the report footers print.  Looks like a bug but I can't find a workaround yet.

[edit 3}
Tried reimporting the subreport with the same results.  Tried moving the images into different subreport sections with the same result.  It seems that the subreport will not print more than two pages.  I've toggled 'can grow' in format subreport and this has to be checked for the subreport to display at all.  The 'number of lines' box next to can grow is always greyed out.

Comment: What happens if you try putting the two images side-by-side in report footer a?

Comment: side by side in report footer a works ok (crystal version 11.5.12.1838).

Comment: What happens if you move the second image further down report section a?

Comment: Bizzarely, it only shows the first image.  If I drag the second image so it is overlapping on top of the first, then the overlapped area shows as white/blank

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve this in the Section Expert by either:

- Checking `New Page After` in the Report Footer A section

or

- Checking `New Page Before` in the Report Footer B section

Comment: I should have said that I've tried that already.  With or without new page after (in report footer a), I always get a blank page at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a workaround.  Looks like a bug in crystal where using a shared numbervar in a suppression formula for a subreport was having unwanted side effects.  I've modified the subreport suppression formula and both images are now printing.